dpkg: error processing package linux-image-6.5.0-44-generic
I am Unable to solve this problem
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up linux-image-6.5.0-44-generic (6.5.0-44.44) ...
Processing triggers for linux-image-6.5.0-44-generic (6.5.0-44.44) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-44-generic
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/btrfs failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-44-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-6.5.0-44-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-6.5.0-44-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-6.5.0-44-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

And here has multiple kernal version and i am unable to remove them
root@steelam:~# dpkg -l | grep linux-image
rc  linux-image-6.2.0-1018-kvm           6.2.0-1018.18                           amd64        Signed kernel image kvm
rc  linux-image-6.5.0-15-generic         6.5.0-15.15                             amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-6.5.0-17-generic         6.5.0-17.17                             amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-6.5.0-21-generic         6.5.0-21.21                             amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-6.5.0-25-generic         6.5.0-25.25                             amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-6.5.0-26-generic         6.5.0-26.26                             amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-6.5.0-27-generic         6.5.0-27.28                             amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-6.5.0-28-generic         6.5.0-28.29                             amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-6.5.0-35-generic         6.5.0-35.35                             amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-6.5.0-41-generic         6.5.0-41.41                             amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-6.5.0-42-generic         6.5.0-42.42                             amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rF  linux-image-6.5.0-44-generic         6.5.0-44.44                             amd64        Signed kernel image generic


Ubuntu 23.10 (along with all flavors) is End-of-Life and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/07/17/ubuntu-23-10-mantic-minotaur-reached-end-of-life-on-july-11-2024/   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

You've provided no Ubuntu product/release details; however the 6.5 kernel was from Ubuntu 23.10, which is EOL thus why it cannot be found. It was also used (as non-LTS kernels are) in the [optional] HWE kernel stack for a LTS, but the release(s) that used it move to supported kernels when/before the release where it came from reaches EOL (as the kernel isn't support any longer).  Your details (as provided) imply you're using an EOL release of Ubuntu
